# Select Last Record Based on few criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

Before

```
+--------+--------+---------+-------+------+
| RowNum | Status | Remarks | SetNo |      |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+------+
|      1 | Q      |         | Set 1 | Want |
|      2 | Q      |         | Set 1 | Want |
|      3 | Q      |         | Set 1 | Want |
|      4 | Q      |         | Set 1 | Want |
|      5 | W      |         | Set 1 | Want |
|      1 | W      | abc     | Set 2 |      |
|      2 | W      | abc     | Set 2 |      |
|      3 | W      | abc     | Set 2 |      |
|      4 | W      | abc     | Set 2 | Want |
|      1 | Q      |         | Set 3 | Want |
|      2 | w      | abc     | Set 3 |      |
|      3 | w      | abc     | Set 3 | Want |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+------+
```

How to select Status=Q and Status=W based on Rownum=lastnumber and setno? **Expectation result is the row with "want" is what i need. Those empty, will be remove**

Tried:

```
select *
from mytable
where (RowNum != (select max(RowNum) from mytable) and status = 'W')
```

Comment: You could SELECT TOP 1 and order by descending RowNum.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand what is your expected result set considering the sample data you provided.

Comment: @NathanChampion tried, not working

Comment: @Raihan updated my expectation result

Comment: Still not clear what you are looking for. Can you try explaining again?

Comment: @user3542587 Why do you want the first `5` rows? If I understand the logic correctly, you only need the `4th` and `5th` row?

Comment: @user3542587 Please provide the sample output from your given input. That will clear your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that for each `setno`, you want all "Q"s and the latest "W". If so, you can use window functions like that:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by setno, status order by rownum desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1 or status = 'Q'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Window Functions. I don't fully understand what you need to do but I would suggest something like:

```sql
with rowNumberedData as
(
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SetNo ORDER BY RowNum DESC) as RowOrder
FROM mytable
)
SELECT * 
FROM rowNumberedData
WHERE (Status = 'Q' OR Status = 'W') AND RowOrder = 1
```

What this will do is add `RowOrder` column to your data and its value will be 1, for the max RowNum in every set. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to check what the `with` syntax is if you are unfamiliar.

Answer (score 0):

This query should return the correct rows

```
with t_cte as (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by setno order by rownum desc) rn
    from testTable t)
select *
from t_cte
where [status] = 'Q'
      or ([status] = 'W' 
          and rn = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question and wanting the last row for each set and then all rows with `q`.  One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by setno order by rownum desc) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 or status = 'Q';
```

There are other ways to express this:

```
select t.*
from mytable  t
where t.status = 'Q' or
      t.rownum = (select max(t2.rownum)
                  from mytable t2 
                  where t2.setno = t.setno
                 );
```

This is similar to the approach you are trying.